# How to have multiple buttons point to one 'dynamic' Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a problem, I am creating an app that has 35 phones to choose from, each phone will have a separate button that will lead to its own Activity. And each of those Activities will contain 9 buttons in them that will also lead to 9 separate Activities.
The problem is this will mean that I will have to create 35 x 9 = 315 Activities!
Surely there is a way to have each phone point to one 'dynamic' Activity that will automatically change its data depending on the phone selected?

My code for one of the phone make's Activity is below:

```
package com.hashmi.omar.store;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AppleActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button buttonip6;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_apple);

    //Sets font for text
    Typeface vodaLt = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "VODALT.TTF");
    TextView vodaHeading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    vodaHeading.setTypeface(vodaLt);

    //Sets up iphone 6 button
    buttonip6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonip6);
    buttonip6.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private void title_activity_iphone6() {
    startActivity(new Intent(AppleActivity.this, Iphone6Activity.class));
}


public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.buttonip6:
                title_activity_iphone6();
                break;
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the xml layout for the above Activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp"
tools:context="com.hashmi.omar.store.Picker"
android:background="#ffffffff"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Select an iPhone"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textColor="#ffff0000"
    android:textSize="31sp"
    android:gravity="center" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="iPhone 6"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="224dp"
            android:layout_height="457dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="@drawable/iphone6_3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="FREE"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.97"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="on Pay monthly from £49"
            android:id="@+id/textView71"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.97" />



        <Button
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonip6"
            android:background="@drawable/choosephonebutton"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="_____________________________"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="iPhone 6 Plus"
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="224dp"
            android:layout_height="457dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:background="@drawable/iphone6_3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="FROM £19"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.97"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="on Pay monthly from £54"
            android:id="@+id/textView81"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.97" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonip62"
            android:background="@drawable/choosephonebutton"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="_____________________________"
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="iPhone 5S 16GB"
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="224dp"
            android:layout_height="457dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:background="@drawable/iphone5s"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="FROM £9"
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.97"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="on Pay monthly from £35"
            android:id="@+id/textView121"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.97" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonip63"
            android:background="@drawable/choosephonebutton"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="_____________________________"
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="iPhone 5C 8GB"
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="224dp"
            android:layout_height="457dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:background="@drawable/iphone5c"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="FREE"
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.97"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="on Pay monthly from £30"
            android:id="@+id/textView151"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.97" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonip64"
            android:background="@drawable/choosephonebutton"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />


    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's not needed, don't create new activities, use fragments. Also, while creating new fragment you can add arguments in constructor, which will customize your widgets.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of the views is the same for every phone, the you can create only 3 different activities, and fill them with appropriate data.
To do this, when selecting a phone in the first activity, put as extra on the intent the id of the selected phone.
Then on the next activity, read that extra, and from there decide what to show.
Same for the third activity,

Comment: I'm new to android, so most of this goes over my head. do you mean 

    private void title_activity_iphone6() {
        startActivity(new Intent(AppleActivity.this, Iphone6Activity.class));
    }
    
    
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
    
                case R.id.buttonip6:
                    title_activity_iphone6();
                    break;
        }
      }

does iphone6 here need to have an id?